# API Platform custom GraphQL output

Tags: symfony, graphql, api-platform.com

I'm working on a GraphQL API using API Platform 2.7 and PHP8. I'm stuck since yersterday on a basic simple thing which is very annoying ><

I want to create a custom Query which does not return my ApiRessource class (User) but another representation (MyFullPerimeterOutput).
When I do it in REST API it works fine :

```
new Get(
    uriTemplate: 'users/my-full-perimeter',
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['user_my_full_perimeter'],
    ],
    output: MyFullPerimeterOutput::class,
    name: 'myFullPerimeter',
    provider: UserProvider::class,
),
```

But when I try to do the same thing in GraphQL Query, it seem the ouput config is not working >< I try many things and nothing works for now.

```
new Query(
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['user_my_full_perimeter'],
    ],
    security: "is_granted('ROLE_USER')",
    output: MyFullPerimeterOutput::class,
    name: 'myFullPerimeter',
    provider: UserProvider::class
),
```

When I go to GraphQL Playground, the query "myFullPerimeterUser" is part of the schema but still return "User" type and not MyFullPerimeterOutput.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I think for GraphQL, you should use a Resolver instead of a Provider, look at the documentation: https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.7/core/graphql/#custom-queries.

Comment: I try that too but this does not change the schema either.

Comment: Here is issues from 4 yours now which are still not resolved at this time. They talking about custom output in GraphQL : 
https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2754
https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2755
Not be able to do that in my API sound for me like a dead end for API Platform ><

Comment: Just for the information, after one week of trying to make API Platform GraphQL do what I need, I quit API Platform GraphQL which is over complicated for basic operation which I can do in no time with Overblog GraphQL. My opinion, for what is worth : not ready for production (at least the GraphQL implementation).